# How to start the MaxxInteractive desktop on Ubuntu?

Tags: .desktop, 21.04

I love the old Motif desktops and stumbled upon an Iris desktop from MaxxInteractive. I installed it on my Ubuntu 21.04 system according to [their instructions](https://docs.maxxinteractive.com/books/mid-v211-installation-guide/page/ubuntu-guide-%28x64%29). The install and update scripts gave the impression that everything installed correctly.

The instructions also requested you to restart the computer. After that one would be able to choose the new desktop from the session menu. I don 't know what a session menu is. After looking around it seems to be a menu option on the login screen showing the desktops you have. I cannot find that option (upper right I got options for disabled, network, volume control and logging options).

In [this blog](https://impsbl.hatenablog.jp/entry/MIDonWSL2_en) I found how to run the desktop from the command line:

```
sudo service dbus restart
sudo service x11-common restart
. /opt/MaXX/etc/system.runtime
. /opt/MaXX/etc/skel/Xsession.dt
```

The services cannot be restarted, they are protected, even from root. I thought that it might not matter as I had restarted the computer already. When I entered the next two commands I did get a MaxxInteractive desktop. But nothing works, no reaction on mouse clicks.

Anybody any idea how to run my shiny new desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install MaXX Interactive Desktop on Ubuntu 21.04 you have to execute the following commands (adapted from [official guide](https://docs.maxxinteractive.com/books/mid-v211-installation-guide/page/ubuntu-guide-%28x64%29)):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cpp libxaw7 libjpeg62 libgtk2.0-0 x11-apps freeglut3 

# Audio control panel in MaXX Desktop
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol

# Older xfonts required as a backward compatibility safety net
sudo apt-get install xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi

# Mandatory Fonts for Modern Look
sudo apt-get install fonts-dejavu fonts-noto

# Additional Fonts for Japanese support
sudo apt-get install fonts-noto-cjk fonts-noto-cjk-extra fonts-noto-cjk

# Terminal Info libs
sudo apt-get install libtinfo5

cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/cdn.maxxinteractive.com/maxx-desktop-installer/MaXX-Desktop-LINUX-x64-2.1.1-Installer.sh
chmod a+x MaXX-Desktop-LINUX-x64-2.1.1-Installer.sh
sudo ./MaXX-Desktop-LINUX-x64-2.1.1-Installer.sh
```

then reboot and find *MaXX Interactive Desktop* in

- GDM

  [image: GDM3]
- LightDM screen

  [image: LightDM]

then login to it and enjoy:

[image: MaXX ID on Ubuntu MATE 21.04]

Comment: Ah, that small icon right down after having clicked your username. Thank you!